# Reading multiple textfile (.txt) from Asset / Raw Folder

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I have multiple text files in my raw folder, I want to show them 1 by 1 according to the selected item on listview.

For example i have seleceted "TwinkleTwinkle" from the listview, the text file would be shown must be TwinkleTwinkle.txt

I have read raw folder file where it has only one text file.But dont know read multiple file from that.Please help me

Here is my code of reading one text file raw folder:

```
try {
        Resources res = getResources();
        InputStream in_s = res.openRawResource(R.raw.heading);

        byte[] b = new byte[in_s.available()];
        in_s.read(b);
        heading.add(new String(b));

        Log.e("Heading", heading.toString() + "  " + heading.size());

        HeadingAdapter myadapter = new HeadingAdapter(context, heading);
        list.setAdapter(myadapter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

heading.txt:

AAAAAAAAA

BBBBBBBBB

CCCCCCCCC

DDDDDDDDD

Here,I need to show it in listview. But all the data are considered as single item at here. I mean, I have only one item which has the above 4 data.

Comment: Can you put example of code?

Comment: Every time you have to read only one file. If you can read one then what is exactly the problem to read another one? Show your code for the first one please.

Comment: Please Check the code

Answer (score 0):

Your code which do reading file is wrong: Check this code

```
try {


    InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.simpletext);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[is.available()];
    while (is.read(buffer) != -1);
    String jsontext = new String(buffer);



    tv.setText(jsontext);

} catch (Exception e) {

    Log.e(TAG, ""+e.toString());
}
```

Comment: May I know,What is  wrong in mycode? I got same result by using your code too.